# jquery multiple files upload using single file element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to upload maximum two files using single file input. I referred this site http://hungred.com/how-to/multiple-upload-single-upload-file-jquery/. But there is problem with delete button. For me the delete 'click' event is triggered twice. That is, if I delete a file, both the two files are getting removed.

Also i need unique ids for the two file inputs. Can any one help me ?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var max = 2;
var replaceMe = function(){
var obj = $(this);
$('#previewRow').css('display','');
if($("input[type='file']").length > max)
{       
        obj.val("");
        return false;
}
$(obj).css({'position':'absolute','left':'-9999px','display':'none'}).parent().prepend('<input type="file" class="fileInput hidden" name="'+obj.attr('name')+'"/>');
$('#preview').append('<div>'+obj.val()+'<a class="clearItem" href="javascript:void(0)">X</a><div>');
$("input[type='file']").change(replaceMe);
$(".clearItem").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(obj).remove();
        return false; //safari fixes
});

}
$("input[type='file']").change(replaceMe);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many jquery plugins.[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is one of the best I have ever found. You can see [demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) also. There is extensive [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) to customize it as per your requirements.

Comment: but i need one like in the above link that I mentioned.